# Regex: remove string that is not prefixed with a specific character

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Using a regular expression, is there a way to remove characters that don't begin with a specific prefix?

For example (and more specifically), in the below string I'd like to only remove new line breaks that don't immediately follow a semi colon:

Initial string:
`"key:\\n value\\n here\\n"`

Desired output string (result)
`"key:\\n value here"`

I've tried using `re.sub(r"[^:]\\n", "", "key:\\n value\\n here\\n")` However, this does not return the desired result, and instead returns the following: `"key:\\n valu her"`

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called a negative lookbehind assertion. In Python's `re` it takes the shape of `(?<!...)` where `...` is the thing that should *not* be behind whatever comes next.

```
>>> s = "key:\\n value\\n here\\n"
>>> re.sub(r"(?<!:)\\n", "", s)
'key:\\n value here'
```